Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined (webpack)
I randomly got this error in my console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at ./node_modules/util/util.js (util.js:109:1)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at ./node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js (index.js:8:14)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at ./src/index.js (index.js:116:1)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:19:1)
at startup:4:1
at startup:4:1

I didn't touch anything in the code the only thing I did was add a png image (I had images in the projects before), add an  to the html file and added some code on the CSS file. Also when opening terminal I get a long list of errors which I can't show here because its more than 25k characters.
I tried changing the webpack.config.js file by adding this code inside plugins:
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "fs": false,
      "tls": false,
      "net": false,
      "path": false,
      "zlib": false,
      "http": false,
      "https": false,
      "stream": false,
      "buffer": false,
      "crypto": false,
      "crypto-browserify": require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
    },
  },

It did reduce the errors to 48 but still I couldn't get any further...
